# Flyway plugin with Maven for integration test

Tags: java, maven, flyway

I want to run Flyway plugin when running integration test in Maven. For integration tests I'm using failsafe plugin.

First of all is it possible to define Flyway plugin two times? One for general usage (eg. from command line) and one for integration test? How to define a seperate configuration in Flyway plugin for integration tests?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this through different executions of the plugin. Each execution can have its own configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an execution for Failsafe's `pre-integration-test` phase with a different configuration, see [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html):

> The Maven lifecycle has four phases for running integration tests:
>
> - pre-integration-test for setting up the integration test environment.
> - integration-test for running the integration tests.
> - post-integration-test for tearing down the integration test environment.
> - verify for checking the results of the integration tests.

and [Guide to Configuring Plug-ins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag):

> **Using the <executions> Tag**
>
> You can also configure a mojo using the  tag. This is most commonly used for mojos that are intended to participate in some phases of the build lifecycle.

For example:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
    <configuration>           
        <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myCompany.com/generalDatabase</url>
        <user>dbUser</user>
        <password>password</password>
        <locations>
            <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration</location>
        </locations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test-database-setup</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>           
                <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myCompany.com/testDatabase</url>
                <user>dbUser</user>
                <password>password</password>
                <locations>
                    <location>filesystem:src/test/resources/db/migration</location>
                </locations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```